# asp.net json serializer issue

Tags: c#, asp.net, json

I have an object that looks like this:

```
public MyObject
{
  public int ObjectID {get;set;}
  public byte ObjectStatus {get;set;}
  public List<MySubObject1> {get;set}
  public List<MySubObject2> {get;set}
  ...
  public List<MySubObject9> {get;set}

  public string MySubObject1InJson {get;set;}
  ...
  public string MySubObject9InJson {get;set;}

  public string ObjectInJson {get;set;}

}
```

This object contains 9 lists and 9 strings for each list in jsonformat and ObjectInJson string for the full object.

And then, I have a list of MyObject.

I'm using JavascriptSerializer: I first serialize each list for each object and store the corresponding string on the InJson variable. Then, I serialize each MyObject by including only the int, byte and json strings of lists. Finally, I serialize the list of MyObject.

I end up with a string that has a lot of \\\" in it and I was wondering if someone had come across such problem with the .net json serializer.

`[{"ObjectID":1492,"ObjectStatus":2,"ObjectJsonFormat":"{\"ObjectID\":1492,\"LStatus\":2,\"LAppoints\":\"[{\\\"AppointID\\\":23350,\\\"AppointType\\\":2,\\\"AppointStatus\\\":3,\\\"AppointDate\\\":\\\"4/23/2011\\\",\\\"AppointTime\\\":\\\"6:49 PM\\\",\\\"AppointSetDate\\\":\\\"4/23/2011\\\",\\\"AppointSetTime\\\":\\\"6:49 PM\\\",\\\"AppointResolvDate\\\":\\\"4/28/2011\\\",\\\"AppointResolvTime\\\":\\\"6:49 PM\\\",\\\"AppointFirst\\\":\\\"NATHAN\\\",\\\"AppointLast\\\":\\\"WEST\\\",\\\"ContactFirstLastListing\\\":\\\"NATHAN WEST\\\"},{\\\"AppointID\\\":23351,\\\"AppointType\\\":1,\\\"AppointStatus\\\":2,\\\"AppointDate\\\":\\\"4/23/2011\\\",\\\"AppointTime\\\":\\\"8:19 PM\\\",\\\"AppointSetDate\\\":\\\"4/23/2011\\\",\\\"AppointSetTime\\\":\\\"8:19 PM\\\",\\\"AppointResolvDate\\\":\\\"4/28/2011\\\",\\\"AppointResolvTime\\\":\\\"8:19 PM\\\",\\\"AppointFirst\\\":\\\"DALE\\\",\\\"AppointLast\\\":\\\"JORDAN\\\",\\\"ContactFirstLastListing\\\":\\\"DALE JORDAN\\\"},{\\\"AppointID\\\":23352,\\\"AppointType\\\":1,\\\"AppointStatus\\\":3,\\\"AppointDate\\\":\\\"4/23/2011\\\",\\\"AppointTime\\\":\\\"9:49 PM\\\",\\\"AppointSetDate\\\":\\\"4/23/2011\\\",\\\"AppointSetTime\\\":\\\"9:49 PM\\\",\\\"AppointResolvDate\\\":\\\"4/28/2011\\\",\\\"AppointResolvTime\\\":\\\"9:49 PM\\\",\\\"AppointFirst\\\":\\\"MANUEL\\\",\\\"AppointLast\\\":\\\"WOODS\\\",\\\"ContactFirstLastListing\\\":\\\"MANUEL WOODS\\\"}]\",\"LNotes\":\"[{\\\"NoteID\\\":14201,\\\"NoteText\\\":\\\"Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostr\\\",\\\"NoteDate\\\":\\\"1/10/2011\\\",\\\"NoteTime\\\":\\\"11:54 AM\\\"},{\\\"NoteID\\\":14202,\\\"NoteText\\\":\\\"Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostr\\\",\\\"NoteDate\\\":\\\"1/10/2011\\\",\\\"NoteTime\\\":\\\"12:24 PM\\\"},{\\\"NoteID\\\":14203,\\\"NoteText\\\":\\\"Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostr\\\",\\\"NoteDate\\\":\\\"1/10/2011\\\",\\\"NoteTime\\\":\\\"12:54 PM\\\"},{\\\"NoteID\\\":14204,\\\"NoteText\\\":\\\"Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostr\\\",\\\"NoteDate\\\":\\\"1/10/2011\\\",\\\"NoteTime\\\":\\\"1:24 PM\\\"}]\",\"LCustom\":\"0\",\"LContact\":\"[{\\\"ContactID\\\":8758,\\\"ContactSort\\\":1,\\\"ContactFirst\\\":\\\"STEVEN\\\",\\\"ContactMiddle\\\":\\\"\\\",\\\"ContactLast\\\":\\\"GARCIA\\\",\\\"ContactFirstLast\\\":\\\"STEVEN GARCIA\\\",\\\"ContactEmail\\\":\\\"steven@garcia.com\\\"},{\\\"ContactID\\\":8759,\\\"ContactSort\\\":2,\\\"ContactFirst\\\":\\\"EDWARD\\\",\\\"ContactMiddle\\\":\\\"\\\",\\\"ContactLast\\\":\\\"MARTINEZ\\\",\\\"ContactFirstLast\\\":\\\"EDWARD MARTINEZ\\\",\\\"ContactEmail\\\":\\\"edward@martinez.com\\\"},{\\\"ContactID\\\":8760,\\\"ContactSort\\\":3,\\\"ContactFirst\\\":\\\"BRIAN\\\",\\\"ContactMiddle\\\":\\\"\\\",\\\"ContactLast\\\":\\\"ROBINSON\\\",\\\"ContactFirstLast\\\":\\\"BRIAN ROBINSON\\\",\\\"ContactEmail\\\":\\\"brian@robinson.com\\\"}]\",\"LAddress\":\"[{\\\"AddressID\\\":14293,\\\"AddressSort\\\":1,\\\"AddressLabel\\\":\\\"Primary Address\\\",\\\"Address1\\\":\\\"1305 S 1st St\\\",\\\"Address2\\\":\\\"Suite 3\\\",\\\"AddressCity\\\":\\\"San Jose\\\",\\\"AddressState\\\":\\\"CA\\\",\\\"AddressZip\\\":\\\"95008\\\",\\\"AddressCounty\\\":\\\"Santa Clara\\\",\\\"AddressCountry\\\":\\\"USA\\\"}]\",\"LBiz\":\"0\",\"LPhone\":\"0\",\"LStatusH\":\"[{\\\"NewStatus\\\":2,\\\"StatusDate\\\":\\\"4/09/2011\\\"},{\\\"NewStatus\\\":3,\\\"StatusDate\\\":\\\"4/14/2011\\\"},{\\\"NewStatus\\\":2,\\\"StatusDate\\\":\\\"4/19/2011\\\"}]\",\"LEmail\":\"0\",\"LCall\":\"[{\\\"CallDate\\\":\\\"5:54 AM\\\",\\\"CallTime\\\":\\\"5/20/2011\\\",\\\"CallDuration\\\":5457,\\\"CallOutcome\\\":1,\\\"CallPhonePrefix\\\":1,\\\"CallPhoneNumber\\\":\\\"4084840241\\\"},{\\\"CallDate\\\":\\\"5:24 AM\\\",\\\"CallTime\\\":\\\"5/23/2011\\\",\\\"CallDuration\\\":11,\\\"CallOutcome\\\":4,\\\"CallPhonePrefix\\\":1,\\\"CallPhoneNumber\\\":\\\"4084840241\\\"}]\"}"},{"ObjectID":1496,`

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to serialize the instance of MyObject. Serializer will automatically serialize the inner lists accordingly.

If you need to ignore any property use the [ScriptIgnore] atribute like russau suggested.

eg.

```
public class MySubObject
{
 // The JavaScriptSerializer ignores this field.
        [ScriptIgnore]
        public int useID { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: The problem is that each sub-object has properties I don't want to include (ie. usedID). So that's why I'm first serializing each list of subobjects.

Comment: Can you put ScriptIgnore attributes on those properties? http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.script.serialization.scriptignoreattribute.aspx

Comment: If I do this, how's the serialization going to be affected? For the moment, I declare a dictionary and use .Add("Property", Object.property) for each of the properties I want to serialize.

Comment: Just serialize the instance of MyObject and mark everything you don't want to serialize inside the subojects with that attribute and it should be fine. You don't need a dictionary to do this.

Comment: I'm getting this: Error during serialization or deserialization using the JSON JavaScriptSerializer. The length of the string exceeds the value set on the maxJsonLength property.

Comment: You could try to set the length higer before serializing but I suspect you are doing osmething else wrong. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.script.serialization.javascriptserializer.maxjsonlength.aspx

Comment: By the way if you do this right you probably don't need the   public string MySubObjectNInJson {get;set;} for each object

Answer (score 0):

You say that you're "triple-JSON-serializing" something, then you'll likely end up with all the quotes. When you convert any object to JSON, you'll get a string which contains quotes (") around the obejct names (and possibly values). If you serialize it again, the quotes inside strings need to be escaped, thus the `\"`. And if you serialize it again, then the escape sign itself is going to be escaped as well, thus the `\\\"`.

Comment: ok, I understand the problem better now. So what's the work-around?